# Need everytime ask user credentials on my .Net intranet application

Tags: iis, credentials

I want everytime ask user credentials on my .Net intranet application.
But can't configure IIS.
Set Windows Authentication enable.
Set application pool Identity to Local Service.
Not resolved my problem.
Only FF ask credentials.
IE and Chrome open site without asking for credentials.
help please.

Answer (score 2):

Windows authentication always tries to use Kerberos/NTLM before asking credentials.  IE and Chrome support it out of the box.  The reason Firfox asks for credentials is because it doesn't trust your IIS domain.  To add your domain to the trust list follow this [walk-through](http://www.grolmsnet.de/kerbtut/firefox.html)

If you want the pop-up box to always appear  don't use Integrated authentication.  Switch either to basic or configure your .Net app to use forms based authentication.

BTW,  integrated authentication is actually more secure,  it doesn't rely on cookies it actually authenticates every request not just your auth page. So, nobody could dump your traffic and steal the session cookie.  The reason it can do it is because Kerberos authentication is very fast.   If you are skeptical,  try to access your site from the machine that is not a part of a domain.

Comment: Need when users open personal page, they always re-entered credentials.. try to do it. Configure activedirectorymembershipprovider not secure realy.